# What does the word 小吉 mean in this context?

Tags: translation

My grandmother went in Japan 50 years ago. During her travel, she collected a note concerning her future, but she didn't speak any words of Japanese. She has kept the note in her wallet for all these years. Now I would like to tell her the meaning of this old note. Could someone please help me? Unfortunately there is a missing character due to a small hole in the middle, I hope it is still undestandable. Thank you.[image: the note]

Comment: Probably this kind of question is off-topic here and It's hard to summarize one sentence because a lot of things being explained. "Slow but steady wins the race." is my first impression. I think the what "omikuji/fortune slip" says is correct since it has been with her for 50 years with it!

Comment: @Marco I edited your question title because it was off-topic and would probably have been closed. This site doesn't accept translation requests but sometimes it's ok to ask about the meanings of specific words or phrases.

Comment: @kandyman:  Even if you edited the title, this is still a translation request.  OP (apparently) doesn't speak Japanese, and shows no research effort.

Answer (score 1):

Without going into too much detail, this piece of paper is known as '[omikuji](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/O-mikuji)'. It's a fortune-telling paper that you pick randomly from a box at shrines and temples in Japan. There is a possible range of rankings from good fortunes to bad fortunes. The word [小吉](https://jisho.org/search/%E5%B0%8F%E5%90%89%23words), written in the top right and pronounced 'shōkichi', indicates that this particular fortune is 'small blessing', one of the good fortunes.